# Outlook with O365 license (E3), how to get notification (on iPhone) when there are new emails in specified folders?

Tags: outlook

So my Outlook (on pc) has about 10 sub-folders and I only want to get notification from 2 of them (on the phone), please let me know how to do it.

Tried "Rule & Alert" but still no luck